# Wordpress: Add all user roles on body class

Tags: php, wordpress

I found some good code to add a single user role to my body classes in Wordpress, but I'm struggling to adapt it to return all user roles for the current user (I have multiple user roles per user). I know `array_shift()` only returns the first item in an array, but I'm not sure what to use instead to return all roles. Any ideas?

```
function get_user_role() {
    global $current_user;
    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);
    return $user_role;
}

add_filter('body_class','my_class_names');
function my_class_names($classes) {
    $classes[] = get_user_role();
    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get all roles without logged in?

Comment: No, all roles of the current user. I have multiple roles per user enabled on my site.

Comment: I have answered, Please try that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! I needed to use `implode()` to return the array as a string. Here's my code:

```
function get_user_role() {
    global $current_user;
    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    $user_roles_list = implode(" ", $user_roles);
    return $user_roles_list;
}

add_filter('body_class','my_class_names');
function my_class_names($classes) {
    $classes[] = get_user_role();
    return $classes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two filters `body_class` and `admin_body_class` to add classes in the body tag.

```
function print_user_classes() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        add_filter('body_class','restrictly_get_current_user_role');//Add user role class to front-end body tag
        add_filter('admin_body_class', 'restrictly_get_current_user_role');//Adds the user id to the admin body class array
    }
}
add_action('init', 'print_user_classes'); 


 function restrictly_get_current_user_role($classes) { 
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $roles = ( array ) $user->roles;
    $classes[] = implode(" ",$roles);
    return $classes;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can please add below code in theme functions.php file to get all author role as class name in body class.

```
add_filter('body_class','my_class_names');

function my_class_names($classes) {
    global $current_user;
    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    if( is_array( $user_roles ) ) {
        $user_role = implode( ' ', $user_roles );
        $classes[] = $user_role;
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_user_role() {
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if($current_user_id > 0){
        global $current_user;
        $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
        $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);
    }else{
        $user_role = array();
    }
    return $user_role;
}

add_filter('body_class','mj_class_names');

function mj_class_names($classes) {
    $class = get_user_role();
    $classes = array_merge( $classes, $class );
    return $classes;
}
```